# Swift Conversion UTF16 to UTF8 and back

Tags: swift, utf-8, utf-16, string-conversion

I'm building an app in Swift an I'm using Backendless as my backend. Turns out their database is UTF8 and thus I can't save emojis without converting the String first.
I can't seem to find the right way to make this conversion to UTF8. I tried this:

```
let encoding = processedText.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

But after this operation the emojis look like this:
%F0%9F%99%84%F0%9F%98%80%F0%9F%98%92%F0%9F%98%89%F0%9F%98%B6%F0%9F%98%B6%F0%9F%98%80%F0%9F%99%81

And I tried this:
    class func stringToUTF8String (string: String) -> String? {

```
    let encodedData = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let attributedOptions = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]
    do{
    let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
    return attributedString.string
    }catch _ {
    }

    return nil
}
```

And the emojis look like this:
ðŸ¤”ðŸ¤”ðŸ‘…ðŸ™ðŸ˜‚ðŸ˜­ðŸ˜ŽðŸ˜‰ðŸ˜…ðŸ˜‰

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: utf 8 supports emojis. Save the data with utf8 encoding. And load it back with utf8 encoding.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question.

Comment: Percent escape is pretty much just for urls

Comment: Also I was able to reproduce what was happening and have a fix. The NSAttributedString was just missing an option that set the proper encoding. But see my answer because attribstring is shouldn't just do what it is being done to it.

Answer (score 4):

First, to create a `String` from `NSData` with utf8 encoding you use

```
String(data: theData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Second, swift String's already are unicode compliant. You do not have to convert them as they already do that. You can access different encodings with their respective properties, e.g. `String.utf8`, `String.utf16`, and so on.

Third, to have NSAttributedString properly utf8 encode your string from data you have to add `NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute` key to the `attributedOptions` dictionary with the value `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

Final notes, I don't know if that's a partial method, but attributed string shouldn't be used just to encode a string.

---

Here is NSAttributedString encoding the data in some format returning gibberish.
[image]

Here is NSAttributedString encoding data as utf8 and returning correct text.
[image]

Here is encoding a string as utf8 string.
[image]

---

I know it's an image, but I wanted the results to show. If these don't work, the database may be stripping bits. Which sucks, also have no idea what to do then, and you probably shouldn't use that database if you want unicode support.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did tried adding NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute to attributedOptions but it didn't work.

I also tried using string.utf8, but if you could tell me how to get from String.UTF8View to String that would be great.

I've been trying to get this to work for 2 days now, it you managed to write a function that works properly, could you please post it here?

Comment: Yeah, I'd be happy, too. Do you have some sample text I can use?

Comment: Thanks a lot hola. I reproduced the results that you have. However, I still get an error when trying to save a converted string to Backendless. I'm waiting for their answer now. Thanks, again.

Comment: You're welcome :) I'm sorry I couldn't help solve your problem! Hope you get it fixed!